# Aliases / multi-tenant of given AWS serverless endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm currently using API Gateway to serve my Serverless endpoints (using serverless framework) and would like to have multiple tenants for a given endpoint.

Deployment is working as expected, I've got an alias `tenant0.domain.xyz` working and I've got the response when I'm calling it.

Now, I'd like to get other tenant for the same deployment, such as `tenant1.domain.xyz`, `tenant2.domain.xyz` and so on.

When I'm adding new Aliases in Route53 such as below:

```
tenant2.domain.xyz.
AAAA
ALIAS d-ea4i6xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. (z1ujrxoxxxxx)
```

I've got the mapping done from `tenant2.domain.xyz` to `d-ea4i6xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` but API Gateway is returning : `{"message":"Forbidden"}%`

Is there any way to fix this response?

Comment: We do this using CloudFront... Multiple CloudFront distributions (one for each client) with the same API Gateway as the origin for each. The simply configure the custom domain for the CloudFront distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sounds really good, so you would recommend defining the final endpoints at CloudFront distribution level and keeping just one API Gateway custom domain?

Comment: No. There should be no API Gateway custom domains, and instead just use CloudFront for all of them.

Comment: But can it prevent the `{"message":"Forbidden"}` then (allowing more origins)? That'd be a great alternative to my non-solution.

Comment: It will allow you to easily configure multiple custom domains for API Gateway... Try it out!

Answer (score 1):

From Oct. 2019, you can add wildcard custom domains to API Gateway!

Then, you can add `*.domain.xyz` as the custom domain of your endpoint (needs a certificate from AWS Certificate Manager(ACM) that is active for `*.domain.xyz` too).

That allows you to issue subdomains to your tenants dynamically without any modifications to DNS anymore. You can route tenants to their services/or/ do a custom logic per tenant by using the parameter `event.requestContext.domainPrefix` lambda as an example.